# Default Email Template Broken in Laravel 5.7.8

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer

I have problem with email template encoding:

This is my template:

**mail/user-created.blade.php**

```
@component('mail::message')
    # Invoice Paid

    Your invoice has been paid!

    @component('mail::button', ['url' => '#'])
        View Invoice
    @endcomponent

    Thanks,<br>
    {{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

**For example in web.php:**

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    $message = (new \App\Notifications\UserCreated(\App\User::first()))->toMail('test@email.com');
    $markdown = new \Illuminate\Mail\Markdown(view(), config('mail.markdown'));

    return $markdown->render('mail.user-created', $message->toArray());
});
```

And I get:

[Preview in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOhLz.png)

[Preview in browser 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCWfP.png)

What is wrong?

--

I moved code to the left:

[Code left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXAnY.png)

[Code left 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0dO2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your email template has to be left-aligned. Just move everything over to the left.

```
@component('mail::message')
# Invoice Paid

Your invoice has been paid!

@component('mail::button', ['url' => '#'])
View Invoice
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

Comment: Nope, look at my post (new preview)

Answer (score 0):

I just found solution:

vendor/tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles/src/CssToInlineStyles.php

Line 129:

Replace:

```
$html = $document->saveHTML($htmlElement);
```

To:

```
$html = $document->saveHTML();
```

But why?